# Should I link a C++ application to shared libraries which are used indirectly

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Let's say you compile a C++ shared library `libBeta.so` which makes use of pre-existing C++ shared libraries `libAlpha1.so`, `libAlpha2.so`, `libAlpha3.so`, etc. If I then write a C++ application which uses `libBeta.so` directly (and therefore indirectly uses the other libraries), should I link my application to `libBeta.so` only, or should I link my application to all libraries?

My intuition tells me that I should only link to `libBeta.so`, because linking to all libraries seems redundant as `libBeta.so` is already linked to the other libraries. However, `undefined reference to` errors are proving my intuition wrong.

Could someone explain me why my intuition might be wrong in particular cases?

p.s.:

- OS: Linux
- Compiler: g++

**EDIT**

As it turns out the tool I was using for compiling has different behaviour for compiling an executable and compiling a shared library. Linkage to sub-libraries were being omitted when compiling a shared library :(

Comment: You say you get undefined references linker error, it might help to tell us what those errors as, then we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared libraries are fully linked entities, and you don't need to explicitly link to their dependencies.

This is unlike static libraries which is only a collection of object files. When you use a static library you *must* link to its dependencies. But for share libraries, no you don't need that.

If you get undefined references, then it's not for the dependencies of the shared libraries you link to. It's either that you are missing linking with your own code, or you actually link with a *static* library.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is exactly what I would expect, but it is not what I am getting. I am using a framework which consists of a large collection of C++ libraries. I created a shared library which interfaces with the parts of the framework that I need. Next I wrote a simple test application which only has main() and calls one function from my library. My application does not compile correctly if I link to my library only, but it does work if I link to all libraries. And yes I checked if all the dependencies are shared libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to link with your direct dependency, `libBeta.so`.

Actually, a few years ago on some Linux distributions you could get away with having indirect dependencies in your executable -- in this case, say, on `libAlpha1.so` -- and as long as the dependency gets loaded at runtime, directly or indirectly, the dependency would get satisfied.

[This is no longer the case](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChangeInImplicitDSOLinking).

Comment: I agree, but please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573081/should-i-link-a-c-application-to-shared-libraries-which-are-used-indirectly/36573308#comment60745566_36573165) comment.

Comment: This means that you did not link your shared libraries correctly. One of your shared libraries references symbols in another shared library, but is not linked with it.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are saying that I forgot to link `libBeta.so` to one of its dependencies and due to that I am forced to link to all sub-dependencies when compiling the application (which ideally should only depend on `libBeta.so`)?

Comment: Well, you probably forgot to link to one of its dependencies. If you can figure out which one, you would only need to link your application directly to that library. But, of course, the right answer would be to link libBeta.so correctly in the first place.

Comment: I completely agree with you and that is frustrating because I double and triple checked everything. My application is currently linked to all libraries of which `libBeta.so` is also being linked to. So, if I am missing a dependency for `libBeta.so` I should also be missing that same dependency when compiling my application (which is not the case). Very confusing :(